# Placing a new value into a section of a big Python bitarray

Tags: python, slice, bitmask, bitarray

Using Python 2.7 and bitarray 0.8.1 to hold several sequenced register values (registers can be from 16 to 512 Byte long).
I want to set a value to a specific part of this bitarray?

For example:

```
from bitarray import bitarray
BYTE = [False, False,False, False, False, False, False, False]
reg = bitarray(512*BYTE, endian='big')
```

How to set the value 0xaa to bits 2048:2055 of reg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using slice assignment.

```
bin_of_aa = "{:b}".format(0xaa)
reg[2048:2055] = bitarray(bin_of_aa,endian="big")
```

Comment: Thank you! this worked, seems I had a problem with creating the sub-part (e.g. bin_of_aa)

Comment: yeah, I tried `bitarray(0xaa)` and got weird results, `bitarray(bin(0xaa))` raised error because `bin` puts the `0b` prefix, another one that would work is `bitarray(bin(0xaa)[2:])` to cut off the prefix but use which ever one you prefer.

Comment: note that `reg[2048:2055]` describes a slice of length 7 but `bitarray(bin_of_aa,endian="big")` is length of 8 so I'd expect it to raise an error but it works, so be careful with that...